# How to solve OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13 in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to store my document file into **'/storage/emulated/0/Download/'**. I got this error :

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Here is my code:

```dart
void download() async {
  http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json", HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer'}});
    
  File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you defined permissions in `AndroidManifest file` like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

for more info try out [this](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) link

Comment: thank you for your reply, I already put these permission but still have error

Comment: @qing are you running this code in real device or emulator?

Comment: run in real device

Comment: So go to the setting/apps and check your application's  permissions too in your real device

Comment: did you check the attached link in my answer?

Comment: after I refer the link I get the error 
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.1.0+1\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip    

BUILD FAILED in 2s

The plugin connectivity_macos could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209137/discussion-between-a-r-and-qing).

Answer (score 73):

In Android Q, you need to add the Following Lines in AndroidManifest file:

```xml
 <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: is it related to the change of targetSdkVersion 29?

Comment: Yes, make sense. 
If your `targetSdkVersion` is 28, don't need this line.
If tour `targetSdkVersion` is 29 or more, need this line

Comment: After adding this, if you get `error: attribute android:requestLegacyExternalStorage not found`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003853/3291390). Specifically, make sure you have `compileSdkVersion = 29` in android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 31):

Just add the following lines in to your android manifest if you're on android 10/Q

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    >
```

Comment: This work for me...
Thank.
I put `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` it work fine now

Comment: Yes this applies only after android 10Q

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem

My solve:

use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

before download action you need check storage permission:

```
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
                  if (!status.isGranted) {
                    await Permission.storage.request();
                  }
```

hope to help some body

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Rajil TL's answer also include

```
targetSdkVersion 28
```

and stop process and run the app. Hot reload is not enough to reflect build.gradle changes.

Answer (score 4):

In my cases none of the solutions worked, finally what worked was to remove from android/app/build.gradle the reference to "targetSdkVersion XX" inside defaultConfig{}

Now everything works as expected, I guess it is a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` this in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application 
android:label="app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
 </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

For android 11 (api 30) and later, android require `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to read and write file.

Add to your manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Don't forget to ask permission from flutter using `permission_handler`

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid && AndroidDeviceInfo().version.sdkInt > 29) {
  await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
} else {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `targetSdkVersion to 28` from the build.gradle file. Rebuild app and run, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

My case was that it was possible to access directory. but couldn't read file.

```
final path= "${await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)}/sub";
final dir= Directory(path);
final l = dir.listSync(); // 1. works fine until here
for( final d in l){
   try{
      final  str = await File("${d.path}/info.json").readAsString(); // 2. permission error here
   }catch(e){
     print(e);
   }
}
```

for solving this problem, I included android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

like belows.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Adding the "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" along with other permissions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with a Galaxy S9. I couldn't use the last used pictures - I had to click on the gallery and photos tab in the top, the app asked for permission again, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**After long Research i find this Solution and it will work on all Android 10+**

Just change **await Permission.storage.request()** to **await     Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()** in your Permission Handler or Requester class.

Because this change will give you full access to Media Storage excluding Restricted Storage.

Detail Example:

First Create a method.

```
Future<AppPermissionStatus> askForPhotoGalleryPermission(
  BuildContext context) async {
var status = Platform.isIOS
    ? await Permission.photos.request()
    : await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request(); 
AppPermissionStatus permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.NotAvailable;

if (status.isGranted) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Granted;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isDenied) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Denied;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isRestricted) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.Restricted;
  return permissionStatus;
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  permissionStatus = AppPermissionStatus.PermanentlyDenied;
}
return permissionStatus;
}
```

How to call this Method.

```
 void getRequiredPermission(BuildContext context) async {
 AppPermissionStatus permissionStatus =
    await AppPermission().askForPhotoGalleryPermission(context);
  setState(() {
  if (permissionStatus == AppPermissionStatus.Granted) {
    hasPermission = true;
  } else if (permissionStatus == AppPermissionStatus.PermanentlyDenied) {
    hasPermission = false;
  } else {
    hasPermission = false;
  }
});
}
```