# flutter video_trimmer package error=13, Permission denied

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, package

I changed targetSdk 29 for upload google playstore. ( google targetSdk policy )

Now I got this error

when I click Execute button, phone die immediately

and error message like this

```
E/FFmpeg ( 9618): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"/data/user/0/myProject/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
```

is there a way to solve this problem?
( targetSdk 28 was no problem )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13 in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558577/how-to-solve-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13-in-flutter)

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work , thx though 