# Trying to delete an audio file but giving exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to delete song file but it is unable to delete and throws an exception of permission denied but permissions are already granted using `permission_handler` and required storage permissions are added in AndroidManifest.xml as well. I have also checked path is valid and file exist before delete which return true. Would anyone help me to solve this.

Error on file.delete() line.

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/storage/0E15-2E06/Music/Call Sound Effect.mp3' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:label="Example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
```

Code snippet:

```dart
       if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
            // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
            // permission was granted
            if (song != null) {
              String? path = song.data;
              File file = File(path);
              bool isExist = await file.exists();
              if (isExist) {
                await file.delete(recursive: true);
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Have you added this in Manifest file `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`?

Comment: @AnhPC03 Yes

<application
        android:label="Music Player"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >

Comment: try this too, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes, each permission is already added. 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>

Comment: checkout this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558577/how-to-solve-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks for that but i already checked that and tried each answers but still failed..

Comment: Can you check if user really have granted the storage permission by going through the android native setting for your app? What you've done above seems working.

Comment: Yeah sir i have verified and checked by going to app setting and permission was allowed there.  Whatever i tried it should work but idk why my code isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `permission_handler`(https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package and have to mention some permissions in the Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, you have to ask Permission of storage before doing storage related operation(In your case deletion of audio file).

```dart
final _permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
if(_permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.isGranted){
/// Delete audio file
}else{
  /// Permission Denied.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this way also but still same error exist.
Also your if condition is not correct. Updated: 
 if (_permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted)