# FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/Users/project/../../../../usr/sbin/authserver' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13

Tags: flutter, macos, flutter-web

this project is working linux system for chrome(web) Flutter web but i get this error in macos

i trying to flutter web development

FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/Users/iberkeugur/development/projectname/../../../../usr/sbin/authserver' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /Users/iberkeugur/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (5 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/iberkeugur/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13 in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558577/how-to-solve-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13-in-flutter)

Comment: no it's not work in my system