# How to creating a path using path provider on my Android 11 device?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a path using path_provider on my Android 11 device. I've been attempting to use path_provider in Android 11 to create a path, but I haven't had any luck so far. I keep receiving an error message that says

> PathAccessException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/UniDownloader' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

This error has been causing me a lot of frustration, as I'm unsure of what might be causing it or how to fix it. Would you happen to have any suggestions or solutions that could help me resolve this issue?

Do you have any suggestions or solutions that could help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You question has been answered in: [How to solve OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13 in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558577/how-to-solve-os-error-permission-denied-errno-13-in-flutter)

I will help u summarize it and adding additional information:

In AndroidManifest, add these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
</application>
```

For **Android 13+ with new storage policy**, you need to add these permissions in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

And use `permission_handler` like this:

```
if (Android_SDK >= 33) {
    isPhotoGranted = await Permission.photos.request().isGranted;
    isVideoGranted = await Permission.photos.request().isGranted;
    isAudioGranted = await Permission.audios.request().isGranted;
    isStorageGranted = isPhotoGranted && isVideoGranted && isAudioGranted;
} else {
    isStorageGranted = await Permission.storage.request().isGranted;
}
```

**Edit:**

Oh right, you can use `getExternalStorageDirectory` of path provider package for create external storage path instead of using directly explicit `storage/emulated/0/...`

Comment: Instead of posting an answer repeating parts of answers from another question, please flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I already flag duplicated before post the answer. Besides, the permission_handler code totally depends on my own experience and not exist in the duplicated question.

Comment: Thank for your help in solving the issue I was facing.